# Convergence of a Sequence. What is N?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

So in real analysis we are given the definition for the convergence of a sequence:

> The sequence $a_n$ converges to its limit $L$ if $\forall \epsilon >0$
>   $\exists$ an $N$(dependent on $\epsilon$) such that $n>N$ which
>   implies that $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$.

I know that $\epsilon$ is like the error factor but I don't understand what $N$ is. All I know is that it $\in$ $\Bbb{N}$.

Can someone elaborate?

Comment: Your definition of convergence seems to be a bit off. Maybe look over it again and see if it makes more sense?

Comment: Fixed it, thanks!

Comment: $N$ tells "how far out in the tail of the sequence" you need to go so that your error is less than the requested $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$N$ is a number beyond which you know that the sequence differs from its limit by at most $\varepsilon$. In the figure below, we are given a sequence and an $\varepsilon$ that should form horizontal lines that bound the sequence for every point to the right of $N$.

[image]

If we can show that for *all* $\varepsilon>0$, we can find an $N$ that allows the sequence to the right of $N$ to be bounded, then the sequence is convergent.

Bear in mind, you have an error in your definition of convergence, as **oernik** has pointed out.

Image credit: http://math.feld.cvut.cz/mt/txta/2/txe3aa2a.htm

Comment: That makes sense. N marks the begining of this bounded interval. Okay, so if epsilon is an arbitrary value, which makes N is an arbitrary value, how do we know how to choose the "right" epsilon?

Comment: @whitenoise (1) $N$ isn't really arbitrary in the sense that there's some $N$ that work and others that don't. In the figure in my answer, $N=13$ would work but $N=4$ wouldn't, since there's points at $6,9,12$ that would be to the right of $N$ but *not* inside the bounds. (2) We don't choose $\varepsilon$, we're given it (or we assume we would be given one). In limit/convergence problems, solving $N$ or $\delta$ when given $\varepsilon$ is a lot like solving for $x$ when given $y$ in a high school algebra problem like $y=2x^2+1$.

Comment: So flipping your question round, we know that we've picked the right $\textbf{N}$ when we've proven that it works as a bound. The specific proof we use will be dependent on the problem at hand.

Comment: "how do we know how to choose the "right" epsilon?"  *THAT* is the hard work and you will have to figure it out on a case be case basis.  And easy example would be if $a_n= \frac {n+5}n$ if we want $|a_n -1| < \epsilon$ we need $|\frac {n+5}n -1| =|(1+\frac 5n)-1|=|\frac 5n|  < \epsilon$ so we need $n > \frac 5{\epsilon}$.  So if $N = \frac 5{\epsilon}$ then if $n > N$ then $|a_n -1| < \epsilon$.  But it could get harder.

Comment: @ Jam I think I got it. So given some the limit of a sequence, and a given some $\epsilon$, we can find the appropriate $N$ such that for all $n>N$ the sequence eventually approaches the limit L.

Comment: @whitenoise Yep, perfect. Then, in order to prove the limit, we'd want to do the same thing for *all* $\varepsilon$ in general, i.e., being as close to the limit as we'd like.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I can explain this with an example.

Let's say $a_n = 2^{100+ n}*3^{-n}$ and now eventually these terms are going to get close to $0$.  The seems reasonable.  Eventually the $3^{-n}$ will "overpower" the $2^{100+n}$ so it will get close to $0$.

Okay,   So we start at $n=1$ and $a_n = \frac {2^{101}}3= 845100400152152934331135470250\frac 23$.  Now suppose we say: Hey! That's not close at all!

And then we counter: we said... *eventually* it gets close to $0$. $1$ is not eventually.  Consider $n= 10$ then $a_{10} = \frac {2^{110}}{3^{10}} \approx 21983000806681009113323241414.842$ that's closer!

And then we say it's pretty sick puppy how calls that "close"  I want it within $1000$ of $0$.

Well, we say,  $2^{100+n}3^{-n} < 1000$ if $2^{100+n} < 1000*3^n$ if $(100+n)\ln 2 < \ln 1000+ n\ln 3$ or if $\frac{100\ln 2 -\ln 100}{\ln 3- \ln 2} < n$.

$\frac{100\ln 2 -\ln 1000}{\ln 3- \ln 2}\approx 159.5$.

Sooo  if $n> 160$ then we will have $|a_n - 0 | < 1000$.

Okay, what if want $a_n$ to be within $1$?  How high does $n$ have to be?

Well, same logic.  If $n > \frac {100\ln 2- \ln 1}{\ln 3-\ln 2}\approx 171$ we will have:  If $n > 171$ we will hav $|a_n - 0| < 1$.

Okay, I want it withing $0.001$.

Okay, that will occur if $n > \frac {100\ln 2 - \ln 0.001}{\ln 3- \ln 2}\approx 188$ so if $n > 188$ then $|a_n -0| < 0.001$

And in fact if we want $a_n$ to be within $\epsilon > 0$ for any epsilon, and $N =   \frac {100\ln 2 - \ln \epsilon}{\ln 3-\ln 2}$, then whenever $n > N$ we will have $|a_n - 0| < \epsilon$.

And that is what $N$ is:

$a_n\to L$ if we can force $|a_n - L|<\epsilon$ by taking large enough values of $n$.

$N$ is the value how big we have to have $n$ be for that to *have* to be true.